# How do I calculate the rate of heat loss from an enclosure when I have a plot of temperature vs time and the enclosure's material details?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, convection, thermal-conduction

I have an enclosure running an ON/ OFF temperature control system. The below graph shows internal air temperature over time. I have the raw data providing actual values.

I have the dimensions of the enclosure, I know its material of construction, and I know the external air temperature over the duration of the system's operation.

The heater inside the enclosure provided 12 V * 1.5 A = 18 W.

How do I calculate the rate of heat loss from the enclosure in Watts for a specific instant?

I am looking to calculate the rate of heat loss from the enclosure in Watts at a given time to compare with the theoretical value of 4.068 W that I had calculated before performing the test. The value of 4.068 W was obtained assuming an air temperature of 18C inside the enclosure and an environmental air temperature of 10C surrounding the enclosure.

[image: Plot of temperature vs time]

Comment: What is the external air temperature, ~13 C?

Comment: Yes, approx. 13C for the duration of the test.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't bother with the peak to trough time. You know the heater rating is 18 Watts (which is energy in Joules per second) and this maintains a more or less constant temperature. Visually the heater is on 50% of the time, so over any given time period the input of energy is 9 Watts on average and this is equal to the energy loss since the temperature is constant. This is your answer, but if you want this in terms of Watts per unit surface area or volume, simply divide that figure by the dimensions of your enclosure.

Comment: Thank you for coming back to me. The reason I am looking to calculate the rate of heat loss from the enclosure in Watts at a given time is to compare with the theoretical value of 4.068 W that I had calculated before performing the test. Is there a way to obtain an instantaneous value to compare to my predicted rate of heat loss? The value of 4.068 W was obtained by assuming internal air temperature of 18 ℃ for the enclosure and an environmental air temperature of 10 ℃.

Comment: The graph looks more or less linear over the 2 degree range concerned so the 9 Watt estimate at 18 degrees C is pretty accurate for a real world value. I would check your calculations for surface area of the enclosure and the thermal rating and thickness of the insulation.

Comment: You could more accurately measure the ratio of the on to off time of the heater, but I don't think that will account for the difference of nearly 5 Watts. Perhaps you could append your theoretical calculations in your question?